# Chaining fetchs 'POST' in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I believe my problem might have been answered more or less but I can't find a satisfactory response. I have a React form with an input and `onChange` lets you select a picture that immediately gets saved in the cloud. The cloud returns a response with an url and an id that I want to pass to the backend database, thus submitted with the form  `handleFormSubmit`. The code below succeeds only if I wait until I get back the response from the cloud (I watch the Dev Tools Components). If I am to quick, the url is 'undefined' because the promise is not set. How can I programmatically properly chain these promises?

I use a state 'photoUrl' for the url and an object called 'Event'.

1. handling the file input `onChange`and send to the cloud and get response back:

```
async function handleSendToCloudinary(e){
  if (e.target.files[0]){
    const formdata = new FormData()
    formdata.append('photo', e.target.files[0])
    fetch(CL_end_point, { method: 'POST', body: formdata})
    .then(res=> res.json())
    .then(data=> setPhotoUrl(data))
  }
}
```

2. and the `onSubmit` on the global form:

```
async function handleFormSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  const formdata = new FormData()
  if (photoUrl) {
    formdata.append('url', await photoUrl.secure_url)
    formdata.append('key', await photoUrl.product_id)
  }
  try {
    setEvents(
      await fetch(myEndPoint, { method: 'POST', body: formdata })
   }...
```

I believe something around `Promise.all` might give a clue but I can't get the solution.

Something like the following fails ('object not iterable')

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve)=> { 
   resolve(formdata.append('url', photoUrl.secure_url)
})
cont p2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
   resolve(formdata.append('key', photoUrl.product_id)
})
Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(()=> {
   setEvents(...)})
```

and the following fails too because of the state `photoUrl`  update probably

```
const p1 = (formdata)=> {
   formdata.append('url', photoUrl.secure_url)
   return promise.resolve(formdata)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to introduce a `loading` flag to your state

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
```

Then you set it to true when uploading your file:

```
    async function handleSendToCloudinary(e){
      if (e.target.files[0]){
        setLoading(true)
        const formdata = new FormData()
        formdata.append('photo', e.target.files[0])
        fetch(CL_end_point, { method: 'POST', body: formdata})
            .then(res=> res.json())
            .then(data=> setPhotoUrl(data))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
        })
    }}
```

And then you disable your submit button while `loading` is true

As a last note, the complexity of your form handling is going to pile up as the time goes (certainly you'd want to handle errors in the future) so you might as well start looking up react state managers and their async handlers (`redux` and `redux-thunk` come to my mind first) in order to move your business-logic away from your components

Comment: yes, the button, thanks. And indeed, my form has to much logic inside. I was more thinking of trying to learn Mobx

Comment: Mobx is going to work too(and in some parts it is better than redux) so you should definitely go ahead and try it!